# Convert signed 13-bit value to signed 16-bit

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is there a prettier way of doing a conversion from a signed 13-bit value to a signed 16-bit value than what i've got below? Both values lies in 16 bit words, the 13-bit value being shifted 3 bits.

```
S = Sign, O = Value bit, X = Unused
a is the signed 13-bit | SOOO OOOO OOOO OXXX
b is the signed 16-bit | SOOO OOOO OOOO OOOO
```

Current implementation

```
b = a & 0x7FF8;        // Remove sign         XOOO OOOO OOOO OXXX
b = b >> 3;            // Shift value 3 bit   XXXO OOOO OOOO OOOO
b = b | (a & 0x8000);  // Add sign            SXXO OOOO OOOO OOOO
```

Comment: Does it get compiled as that? I've seen compilers do some tricky optimisations for things like this that my mortal brain cannot comprehend. Also I suppose the architecture you're targeting could be helpful. You could always be targeting some CISC with a `cs13bvts16b` instruction and never know it...

Comment: Can you confirm that we're talking about (a) 2's complement representation and (b) C (or a closely related language) ?

Comment: @PaulR a) You are right, it 2's complement and b) I just typed some pseudo C as I'm seeking a general solution and my implementation will use structured text.

Answer (score 3):

Right shift on signed types is implementation defined (in C, at least - you didn't actually mention what language you're using here), but assuming your compiler is like 99% of other compilers and does an *arithmetic* right shift on signed values then all you need is:

```
b = a >> 3; // Syyy yyyy yyyy yxxx => SSSS yyyy yyyy yyyy
```

Obviously you should test this and/or check your compiler documentation.

[Note also that this assumes that we're talking about 2's complement representation for the values - again it's not specified in your question.]